# GET method for download WSDL

Tags: wsdl, rest

I want to download wsdl file programmaticaly, using my Web JavaScript application. First I do Oauth login and get all tokens. Then I try to download WSDL file using JavaScript:

```
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onload = function () {
            alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://ap1.salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp", true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
```

When this code executes I always get error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ap1.salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin MyLocalHost is therefore not allowed access.

Could you suggest me how can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to deal with the CORS request to the Salesforce resource, I would start here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/.

Comment: I read this topic and issue is that I can't manage salesforce  server side. All I have is client-side application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideas: [Support of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in RESTful API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZojFAAS).

> Coming in the next release

---

That said, the resource you are requesting isn't something I would typically associate with a REST request. You might need to specify the sid cookie with the accessToken (sessionId) to request the Partner API WSDL. One option here would be to create your own RESTful web service in Apex that does the required HttpRequest for the WSDL.

Something else to note. The Partner WSDL is static within a release. There is nothing stopping you taking a copy and storing it somewhere accessible.